# How to programatically check if Bubbles are globally enabled?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-bubbles

Is there an API available to check whether Bubbles are enabled from Developer Options?

There is an API `NotificationManager#areBubblesAllowed` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#areBubblesAllowed()) but this only checks Bubble permission in application level.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the correct values:

```
Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, "notification_bubbles")
```

0: Disabled 1: Enabled